# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial' with connection for pi and arduino

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I'm trying to connect Raspberry pi and Arduino UNO with just a simple code.

For Arduino,

---

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println("Hello Pi");
  delay(1000);
}
```

---

For pi,

---

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

while 1:
    print ser.readline()
```

---

I installed libraries, maybe all I need,

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip 

sudo pip install pyserial

sudo pip install serial
```

and more

Also my python file name isn't serial. It's tq.py

Is there any recommendation for this problem..?

Answer (score 0):

There's a namespace conflict between `pyserial` (the module you want to use) and `serial` (a module for serializing/deserializing).

Basically python is looking for the `Serial` object in the incorrect module and because it doesn't exist in that module you're getting an error.

Assuming you don't need both you can just do:

```
pip uninstall serial
```